# Close button + Esc for the save query dialogue in Data Explorer

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, data-explorer

When I vote to close a question on Stack Overflow, the dialogue layer shows a close button at the top left corner:

[image: Close button in Stack Overflow’s vote to close dialogue]

and pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd> dismisses the dialogue.

However, when I want to save a query in Data Explorer, there’s no close button:

[image: No close button in Data Explorer’s save query dialogue]

and <kbd>Esc</kbd> has no effect.

Could Data Explorer save query dialogue (and maybe other dialogues in SEDE?) have a close button and accept <kbd>Esc</kbd>?

Answer (score 1):

The Data Explorer workflow has been updated so that you no longer need to explicitly save queries, so there's no longer a dialog to close.

If you come across any other dialogs that can only be closed by clicking (or is missing a close button altogether), those should likely be addressed, but I couldn't think of any other examples off the top of my head.